# Skip multiplies of 5 through 17 terms C++

Tags: c++

I would like to write a simple program that skips all multiples of 5 such that there are 17 terms in the result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int num = 1;
int i = 1;
while(i <= 17){
    if(num%5 != 0){
        cout << num <<endl;
    }
    i++;
    num++;
}
```

I expected it to be like this: 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21

However, for some reason it ends when the output reaches 17, instead of having 17 terms. So: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17

How do I fix this?

Comment: `while(i<=21)` ?

Comment: @JakeFreeman I would like the program to be able to incorporate large numbers without an expected output. So assume that I don't know the answer

Comment: @Steve just `i++` in the `if` block otherwise it would get stuck when `num==5`

Comment: @JakeFreeman Yep, already deleted it :)

Comment: @Steve worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: @JakeFreeman Yeah I need to wait another 7 mins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix to your problem is:

```
while(i <= 17){
    if(num%5 != 0){
        cout << num <<endl;
        i++;
    }

    num++;
}
```